# Rapid/ Slow Expansion in Gases

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

How is rapid expansion of gases different from slow expansion?

Comment: Under the usual meanings of 'slow' and rapid,' one will be isentropic and the other won't.

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail? (on molecular level)

Comment: i think @John1024 wanted to say "reversible" not "isentropic". The latter is reversible *and* adiabatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most physics education teach learners about slow vs rapid expansion of gases in thermodynamics. This is often misleading, but only because many miss the point that slow expansion accounts for heat flow to and from the gaseous system and is assumed that the gas reaches thermodynamic equilibrium with the external system; and that rapid expansion assumes heat flow is negligibly small since the process happens over a short time, and the process is idealized to be adiabatic. Ultimately these two modes of gas expansion has no difference in their underlying mechanisms, and it is only the differing importance of heat flow that makes each model differently important in different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

In slow expansion the gas is always in equilibrium state.
Rapid expansions are basically rapid so there is no time for energy transfer so they are adiabatic.